# Is it possible to automatically create additonal properties on a doctrine entity, maybe by annotation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity property, and based on that property "name" I would like to build out an additional 3 properties, and it would be awesome if I could do this by an annotation, trait, or extension etc.

This is data being input from users in multiple languages.

There are many entities, and within those entities, there can be many properties to translate

Here is an example entity

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=EntityRepository::class)
 */
class Entity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $text;
}
```

I would like to "automatically" expand it to function as if it was written like this

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=EntityRepository::class)
 */
class Entity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $text;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $textUpdatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $textEng;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $textEngUpdatedAt;
}
```

The "translatable" column can be either `text` or `string` (`varchar`) type.  The timestamps will be automaticaly set when the property is updated.  It is used for "dirty" tracking.

I thought Annotation would be my answer, but as I tried setting up a custom annotation, I could not even get the propperty name passed in automatically.  I would just get an empty class, and if I added code like the doctrine documentation gave, I would have to provide all the info I was looking for.

Comment: Do you want this for just a single column/property, or do you want to be able to "tag" a column as translatable so you can use this whenever? Even if you were able to magically do this, your object from PHP's perspective wouldn't have these properties so you'd have to implement PHP's magic methods to get/set them. If you don't have a lot of these, it might just be easiest to bite the bullet and write them all out.

Comment: If you are using Symfony there's a [make:entity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) command that you can run that allows you to edit your Entities. It also ties into the Doctrine migrations bundle too nicely for deployments

Comment: @ChrisHaas, yes, this situation is in many entities and multiple columns in some entities.  I think that yes, I am going to have to "bit the bullet" and just actually create them all each time

Comment: @hppycoder I do use `make`, it helps speed things up.

Comment: Just for info, you could make a TextTrait with your four annotated properties (text, textUpdatedAt etc) and then use the trait in your main entity.  The four properties will be mapped.  You will need a different trait for each named property but at least you could share the trait among multiple entities.  You might also look at a little used feature known as 'embeddable' properties which are basically crude value projects. You should also probably do some searching for translatable entities.  Not sure I see the value in storing the translations in the entity itself.  But I guess it depends.

Comment: @Cerad I will take a look at embedables, I have used them before.  The reason the translation is stored in this way is because it is about data being entered (in any language) that is destened for an English speaking reader.  The data is part of reports, and during review can be seen as the native language, english, or both at the same time.  The UI is handled by symfony/translation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using an embedable I have a reusable class that "seporates the consern" of translations and timestamps and automatically creates the extra columns.

By creating an embeddable class like this

```php
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Embeddable
 */
class TranslatableText
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $text;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="change", field="text")
     */
    private $textUpdatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $textEng;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="change", field="textEng")
     */
    private $textEngUpdatedAt;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getText(): ?string
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

    public function setText(string $text): self
    {
        $this->text = $text;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTextUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->textUpdatedAt;
    }

    public function getTextEng(): ?string
    {
        return $this->textEng;
    }

    public function setTextEng(?string $textEng): self
    {
        $this->textEng = $textEng;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTextEngUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->textEngUpdatedAt;
    }
}
```

I can then use this annotation on any property in an entity

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\Embedded(class="\App\Model\TranslatableText")
     */
    private $newsMy;
```

In the databse this results in the following table columns

```
news_my_text
news_my_text_updated_at
news_my_text_eng
news_my_text_eng_updated_at
```

the timestamps are set automatically by the doctrine timestampable extension.  acessing the data is also straight forward

```
$entity->getNewsMy()->getText(); // gives "native" text
$entity->getNewsMy()->getTextEng(); // gives translated english text
```

I have a second embeddable class for "string" type properties as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your case i guess you could use Event Subscribers like they use it in easyadmin [Here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/events.html),

or as they use it with doctrine [Here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-subscribers)

the user can just set the text and in Persist Event you could add the rest of the class attributes